# error calling function in xcode

Tags: xcode, swift

im having a strange issue on my xcode proyect.
im getting the following error: "MISSING ARGUMENT FOR PARAMETER #1 IN CALL"

on signup.swift file im calling:

```
let appDelegate : AppDelegate =   UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
AppDelegate.login()// here it crashes in the login
```

the login func on my appDelegate file is the following

```
    func login() {

    // remember users login
    let username : String? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("username")

    // if logged in
    if username != nil {

        let storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let myTabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("tabBar") as? UITabBarController
        window?.rootViewController = myTabBar

    }


}
```

any ideas how to solve this issue?
thanks

Comment: Is that a copy paste of the actual code? Why are you using the class instead of the instance?

Comment: Call it on the instance `appDelegate.login()` rather than the class `AppDelegate.login()`

Comment: **Swift** is case-sensitive. `appDelegate` is an instance variable, while `AppDelegate` is a class.

Comment: Take a look at the explanation I gave in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907598/swift-function-call-list-incorrect-parameter-type/34907698#34907698): you are using the class rather than the instance and the call therefore expects an instance to be passe along.

Comment: you where right luk2302, i was using the class, that was the error. Thanks