# Can I retrieve an item from a tuple in the same way as indexing an item from an array in a for loop?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, for-loop, tuples

The following is part of my code for a custom UICollectionViewCell class, and I am getting an error in my `for` loop that says the type of tuple in the function definition has no subscript members.  Does anyone know if there is a way to retrieve the members of tuples as if they were arrays?  Thank you!

```
    func initializeStuff(objectType: AnyObject, xOriginCgFloat: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat?), yOriginCgFloat: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat?), width: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat?), height: (CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat?))  {

        if objectType === UIButton.self {
            if xOriginCgFloat.2 != nil || yOriginCgFloat.2 != nil || width.2 != nil || height.2 != nil {
                for index in 0..<3 {
                    var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.init(x: xOriginCgFloat[index], y: yOriginCgFloat[index]), size: CGSize.init(width: width[index], height: height[index])))

                    buttonArray.append(button)
                }
            } else {
                fatalError("Each tuple for a button object must have exactly three values.")
            }
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason you have to use a tuple of `CGFloat`s instead of an array of `CGFloat`s?

Comment: @RPatel99 Yes.  From https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494236/how-do-i-check-the-number-of-values-in-an-array-that-is-a-udf-parameter which I posted yesterday.  I guess it can check for errors during compilation which I guess reduces the likelihood of crashing the app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any way to iterate a tuple in swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299045/any-way-to-iterate-a-tuple-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24299045/any-way-to-iterate-a-tuple-in-swift) for the inspiration to this answer. First add this function somewhere accessible in your code:

```
func iterate<Tuple>(_ tuple:Tuple, body:(_ label:String?,_ value:Any)->Void) {
    for child in Mirror(reflecting: tuple).children {
        body(child.label, child.value)
    }
}
```

Then use this updated version of your code:

```
if objectType === UIButton.self {
        if xOriginCgFloat.2 != nil || yOriginCgFloat.2 != nil || width.2 != nil || height.2 != nil {
            var buttonOneData:[CGFloat] = [CGFloat]()
            var buttonTwoData:[CGFloat] = [CGFloat]()
            var buttonThreeData:[CGFloat] = [CGFloat]()
            var buttonsData:[[CGFloat]] = [buttonOneData,buttonTwoData,buttonThreeData]
            var tuples = [xOriginCgFloat,yOriginCgFloat,width,height]

            for tuple in tuples {
                iterate(tuple) {
                    var indexStr = $0! //index = .0,.1,.2, etc
                    indexStr.remove(at:indexStr.startIndex) //remove the . from .0,.1,.2,etc.
                    let index = Int(indexStr)
                    buttonsData[index].append(CGFloat($1 as! Int)) //$1 = the value of tuple.0, tuple.1, tuple.2, etc.
                }
            } 

            for (index,buttonData) in buttonsData.enumerated() {
                var button = UIButton(frame: CGRect.init(origin: CGPoint.init(x: buttonData[index], y: buttonData[index]), size: CGSize.init(width: buttonData[index], height: buttonData[index])))
                buttonArray.append(button)
            }

        } else {
            fatalError("Each tuple for a button object must have exactly three values.")
        }
}
```

It is very convoluted and I'm honestly not a big fan of it, but if you need to use tuples, then this will (probably) work for you. I basically used the iterate function from the list at the top of this answer to go through your tuples and add them to arrays that separated the data from the tuples into an array of button data, which I then made an array so you can iterate through that and make the actual buttons.

Comment: Thank you!  With the number of times I was going over the same thing, it did definitely seem convoluted.  That said, what I realized from another comment was that my error messages are basically just for me to debug my code because the `func` is in a custom class.  Also, do you know why the `func` is not giving me the parameters when I try to call it in the same class? It gives `self.initializeStuff(self: customCollectionViewCell)`

Comment: Are you calling the `initializeStuff` from a separate static function? I need to see more of your code to give you a more specific answer.

Comment: No, I am calling it from outside the function but in the same class

Comment: How can I send a message?  It is rather long

Comment: Oh god, please don't do this.

Comment: @Alexander Why not? Do you know a better way to do what he's asking if he wants to use tuples? If so, feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: @RPatel99 I can't give a suggestion for how I would do it, with so little information given. I wouldn't be having the OP's issue in the first place though, because I wouldn't have a "height" variable of type `(CGFloat, CGFloat, CGFloat?)` (wut?) OP's abusing tuples, and bolting on iteration with `mirror` doesn't address that underlying issue.

Comment: @Alexander I asked why he's using tuples as well in the comments to the original question and he provided me with a link to a previous question where someone told him to use tuples rather than arrays. Also the height is a tuple of three CGFloats because each one corresponds to the height of a button (same for each of the other params). The answer I provided is just to answer the question, which was basically to fix his code, and my answer was the best I could give without drastically reworking the entire thing.

Comment: @RPatel99 And in response, I commented (directed at OP), not to use your approach, because reworking the thing is the right way to go. That's not a criticism of your answer or effort (there's really no better way to iterate a tuple), I'm just called it like it is: something to be avoided

Comment: @Alexander Ah okay I understand. I agree, and that's why in my answer I said that I myself am not a fan of it. At the time of answering the question I wasn't sure why he was using tuples, so my answer is for if there is no way for his to function the way he wants it to unless it uses tuples (I don't know why that would be the case, but since we don't know all of his code, it's impossible to know for sure)

Comment: @OP In regards to your question, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34907598/swift-function-call-list-incorrect-parameter-type)

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a function like this instead:

```
func makeButtons(frames: [CGRect]) {
    for frame in frames {
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame)
        buttonArray.append(button)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the UIButton, but I also have UIView and UILabel, so for those other two would I just make two additional, exactly similar functions?

Comment: Realistically it's not clear why you need a function for this at all. The main point is that you should use an array of `CGRect`, which is guaranteed to be consistent, rather than four arrays/tuples of `CGFloat`, which might have inconsistent lengths.

Comment: Thank you!  I had made functions because I didn't want to have to initialize 3 UIButtons, 2 UIViews, and 2 UILabels all by hand.  I thought there had to be a shortcut.